# Weird prototype pointing

Tags: javascript

I am reading this: http://killdream.github.com/blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop/index.html

and i've encountered some code that i can't understand:

```
function Person(first_name, last_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name
    this.last_name  = last_name
}

// Defines the `name' getter/setter
Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'name', { get: get_full_name
                                                , set: set_full_name
                                                , configurable: true
                                                , enumerable:   true })
```

Why is he using `Object.defineProperty` on `Person.prototype` and not simply on `Person`? 
Why not simply include `name` in the definition or make `Person.name = bla...`?

(EDIT: SOLVED)
also, why am i seeing this endless loop of prototype reference??

[image: why am i seeing this endless loop of prototype reference?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If he'd use `Object.defineProperty` on `Person` then you'd define a property on that function and **not** on the instances you create with `new Person`.

I.e. given `Object.defineProperty(Person, ...)` you were able to do

```
Person.name = 'foo';
```

but that would not really help in this situation.

On the other hand, properties of the prototype are shared by all instances and therefore it makes sense to define this property on the prototype.

Here `Person` is a *constructor function* which is supposed to be called with the `new` keyword. It probably will help [to read about what `new` is doing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), in order to understand why `Person.prototype` has to be extended.
The gist: When called with `new`, inside the function, `this` will refer to an empty object inheriting from `Person.prototype`.

Regarding the second part: Each function has a `prototype` property, and each prototype has a `constructor` property referring to its "parent" function. Thus you have a self referencing structure:

```
Person.prototype.constructor === Person;
```

What you showed is **not** the prototype chain, which can be revealed by inspecting `__proto__`.

I could simulate the same with:

```
var a = {};
a.b = {a: a};
```

and I could access `a.b.a.b.a.b.a.b.a.b.a` indefinitely.

Comment: thanx, but i'm not sure i understood completely the first part: when i use `Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype` i am getting the ability to use the getter/setter function on any instance of `Person`? or did I got it wrong?

Comment: Basically yes, that's why you want to extend the prototype. I just added *On the other hand, properties of the prototype are shared by all instances and therefore it makes sense to define this property on the prototype.* That's why we use prototype inheritance.

Comment: And if so, why is there a difference between adding a property directly to a constructor function vs. adding it via `prototype `?

Comment: When you call a function with the `new` keyword, an empty object is created which inherits from the functions prototype (i.e. `Func.prototype`). That's what `this` refers to inside the function. But there is no special meaning for other properties assigned to a function. For example, functions also have the properties `apply` and `call` but they are not related at all to what  happens when you call the function with the `new` keyword. In the end, functions are just objects too, so JavaScript lets you assign properties to them like to any other object.

Comment: Maybe you have to read the article more carefully (or it is not good), after all it is called *Understanding JavaScript OOP* ;) What I told you should be explained in some way there. *edit:* Ah, I see, he does not really explain *why* it has to be *Person.prototype*.

Comment: can you explain why? i still don't get it... `Person` is the constructor, it would make sense if I did `var guy = new Person` and then `Object.defineProperty(guy.prototype`

Comment: No. `guy` does not have a `prototype` property as it is an object. Only functions have. You *could* do `Object.defineProperty(guy, ...` but then only this instance would have that property and you'd have to do that for every instance you create. If you call `Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, ...`, then *every* instance will have that property, because they all inherit from that object. Don't know how to make it clearer. Every instance inherits from the constructor function's prototype, hence you define properties on the prototype which should be shared by all instances.

Comment: `Person.prototype` does **not** refer to the prototype the function itself inherits from. This reference is kept in `Person.__proto__` and can normally not be accessed. `Person.prototype` is an object from which the instances created by this function  will inherit.

Comment: oh..! I thinkI finally got it :) I didn't understand the differance between object and object.prototype. thanx for the patience